Flutter :Ignore pointer and its children: Can a child still not be ignored?
This is for flutter web.
I have a widget which I wrapped in IgnorePointer() so that my MouseRegion(cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,) would work for Text() widgets. Without IgnorePointer() ,hovering on text widgets would show a Ibeam cursor.
Now, I have a child which is nested like 20 widgets more in the widget tree which need to be clicked on to open some page. Using IgnorePointer() as a super-parent makes this not possible . Is there a way to make it clickable?
 child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: onCardTap,
          child: MouseRegion(
            cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                     **Insert hundred of lines of Code**
              child: **IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Remix.information_line,
              color: AppColors.neutral60,
            ),
            onPressed: () async {
              await showDialog(
                context: context,
                barrierDismissible: false,
                builder: (context) => _PriceRatingDialog(
                  title,
                  price,
                  priceAssessment,
                  mobileDeLink ?? '',
                ),
              );
            },
          ),**
                          ),
                            ),
                          )

So the Gestion detector of the icon button now cant be used .Is there a Workaround?
What i tried : Wrapping each other element in MouseRegion() which is a bad solution because those single elements are used in many places in my application.
So wrapping the parent is a must to avoid conflict and bad behaviour(showing "click" cursor where it should not) in other pages in my website.
